# To Display a Stock Details

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to display the stock details like MRP, Sales Rate , Tax Amount and so on.

I used three grid views to make a entry in my form. They are,

1. GV Purchase
2. GV Product Details - (It is used to show the product name and product code )
3. GV Stock Details - (It is used to show the Quantity, MRP, Sales Price and so on)

I used SQL Query for populate the DB records in my grid view.

I select a Product A from Product Grid view in my form ,the Stock grid will show the corresponding data of the Product A

My DB records,

```
   code   Name  QTY  MRP    S.Rate

   aa11   Pro A  5  120.00  130.00

   aa11   Pro A  2  130.00  150.00

   aa12   Pro B  4  100.00  110.00

   aa13   Pro C  2   50.00   60.00
```

When I select Pro A in GV Product Details in my form. The GV Stock Details will be shown the QTY, MRP, S.Rate for the Pro A

But My Query returns like this format

```
    aa11 Pro A  5  120.00  130.00 

                2   130.00  150.00

                4   100.00   110.00

                2     50.00    60.00
```

This is my Query,

```
   select s.*,iif( d.NewSalePrice is null,s.saleprice1,d.NewSalePrice)as NewSalePrice,Pdate from (select s.*,p.ProductFullName,p.ProductCode from Stock s,Product p where s.productfullcode=p.ProductFullCode) s left join(select Productfullcode,MRP,PUnitPrice,NewSalePrice,Pdate from DailyPricing ) d on s.ProductFullCode=d.ProductFullCode where  s.MRP=d.MRP and s.UnitPrice=d.PUnitPrice and Pdate=(select MAX(Pdate) from DailyPricing where  PUnitPrice=s.UnitPrice and mrp=s.MRP and ProductFullCode=s.ProductFullCode) order by ProductFullCode
```

How to I get Stock details only matched by Pro A

Note : These table format is just a model for my Table

Thanks in Advance,

Vinayak vk.:-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably simplify your query, and add a where clause for the product name you need.

Haven't tested it against mock data, but something like this SQL:

```
select 
    s.*, 
    p.ProductFullName, 
    p.ProductCode,
    coalesce(d.NewSalePrice, s.saleprice1) as SalePrice,
    max(d.Pdate) over (partition by p.ProductFullCode, s.mrp, s.UnitPrice) as MaxPdate
from Product p 
join Stock s on s.productfullcode = p.ProductFullCode
join DailyPricing d on (s.ProductFullCode = d.ProductFullCode and s.MRP = d.MRP and s.UnitPrice = d.PUnitPrice)
where p.ProductFullName = 'Pro A'
order by p.ProductFullCode
```